# How to improve grouping by head

Tags: scala, collections

Suppose I have a piece of code like this:

```
case class A(xs: Seq[Int])

def groupByHead(as: Seq[A]): Map[Int, Seq[A]] = 
  as.filter(_.xs.nonEmpty).groupBy(_.xs.head)
```

`groupByHead` works Ok but I don't like `groupBy(_.xs.head)` because `head` is unsafe. How would you improve it ?

Comment: .head is not unsafe since you know _.xs is non-empty (I dislike the fairly common claim that x.head is unsafe. It's only unsafe if x can be empty, and it often can easily be shown that it cannot be)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul You personally may know that this is safe, but the compiler does not, and the link between `notEmpty` and `head` might not be obvious to everyone. Also, saying that something is not safe in all circumstances is surely the very definition of "unsafe".

Comment: 'Also, saying that something is not safe in all circumstances is surely the very definition of "unsafe"' Not from my point of view, no. Going for a walk is by not safe in all circumstances (e.g. on an active vocano) but arguing that by definition that makes walking "unsafe" is a bit weird. Context matters.

Comment: " the link between notEmpty and head might not be obvious to everyone." I don't want anyone on my team who doesn't  find that a sequence being non-empty implies it has a first element obvious. But YMMV..

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul *"you know"* != *"compiler / proof assistant knows"*. If *"it can be shown"*, it doesn't mean that it's guaranteed by the type system. It doesn't matter who you have on your team or not: this line might not go through some formal verification tools, whereas both Tim's solution and mine contraption probably would, because we completely bypass taking `.head` of a list in the first place. It really is a matter of perspective, to appreciate some of the answers, one would probably have to take the Python hat off, and put an Agda hat on...

Comment: As it happens, I'm fairly aware of what formal verifiction can do (I have read books  on Denotational Semantics for fun). It really is, as you say, a matter of perspective, and I think I could equally argue you are not appreciating mine. But end of, let's argue over a beer if we ever meet f2f.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul *"not appreciating"* - This entire thread is a rare example where everybody (including people who provided alternative solutions) unanimously agree that OP's original solution proposed in the question is the best & simplest, so I'm not sure what the reason for the lengthy discussion even is.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you *could* `collect` only those `A`s where the sequence is non-empty, and from then on convert it into a value that is simultaneously a constructive proof of the non-emptiness of the sequence:

```
def groupByHead(as: Seq[A]) = 
  as.collect { case a @ A(h +: t) => (h, a) }.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

but that looks a bit artificial. In this particular case, the "unsafe" `.head` seems like the lesser evil, there is not much that could go wrong between the `filter` and the `groupBy`.

Comment: Thanks. I agree it looks a bit more complicated than the "unsafe" solution.

Comment: "In principle, you could collect only those As where the sequence is non-empty," the OP already has done - that's what the filter does?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul The sentence doesn't end there. It's the second part that is different from what OP did initially: converting the sequences *"into a value that is simultaneously a constructive proof of the non-emptiness of the sequence"*, in this particular case, a tuple containing the sequence itself and the separately stored `head`. The difference is that taking `head` is unsafe, whereas taking first projection of a tuple is.

Comment: Sure, but this seems to have no advantages over the OP's original. First remove all elements that have an empty sequence then groupBy the result. You don't need that proof in the second part - the filter (or collect) has already ensured the sequences are not empty. So (IMO) it's no improvement, being (slightly) slower, and (again IMO) less clear what's going on.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul It has the advantage that it *obviously* doesn't use any operations that could possibly throw any exceptions. Projection to first component of a tuple *never* throws anything.

Comment: As I said, IMO :)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul There is no place for "opinions", at least not as long as we are talking about the capabilities of the type system. OPs code implicitly smuggles a sigma-type `Sigma_{a: A} a.xs.nonEmpty` between the `filter` and the `groupBy` step, because such sigma/sum-types are not directly expressible in Scala's type system. My code does not make any non-expressible assumptions about the type, instead it creates the pair `(h, a)` explicitly, which roughly corresponds to the previously described sigma type: `a` is value, `h` is an explicit constructive proof of non-emptiness.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul That this looks like a very artificial and tortured contraption: yes, agree, that's what I remarked in the very first version of my answer right from the beginning.

Comment: "at least not as long as we are talking about the capabilities of the type system". Fair enough. I'm not sure we were talking about that, though

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
def groupByHead(as: Seq[A]): Map[Int, Seq[A]] = 
  as.groupBy(_.xs.headOption).collect{ case (Some(key), x) => key -> x }
```

Comment: Thanks. It's nice but I would prefer the "unsafe" version.

Comment: As always, it would be good to understand why this got a downvote (and the other answer did not)

Comment: @Tim The first answer got total `-1` and got deleted... Not sure why this answer here would get a downvote though, I still think that this is the best proposal.